# VMware Player Vm resolution way too big

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, vmware-player

[image]

The resolution of this VM has suddenly increased a lot. Not sure how to fix this.

My VM display settings:

[image]

I changed the Display resolution within the VM but on restart it changes to the max again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the settings, the VM-monitor has the same resolution as the host-monitor because you/a tool has set that.
If you want to edit, you cant edit it, when the VM is running.

1. Stop the VM.
2. Go to the VM-settings.
3. Change Monitors to "Specify monitor settings"
4. Set the resolution, that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Check the main computer screen resolution. ex: 1366×768
2. Go to VM player

   > Settings -> Select Display -> Specify the max screen resolution
   > For example: 1600×1200
3. Launch Virtual OS.
4. Modify the display resolution in Virtual OS –> 1366×768.
5. Restart Virtual OS.

You should see the Virtual OS screen fits into the main OS screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:
Remove $HOME/.config/monitors.xml and reboot. It should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

As venkat basically noted, make sure your client (VM) and host (your computer) have the same resolution.

### Question

As a user, I had not changed anything, so why did it all of a sudden happen?

### Overview

Something HAD changed: My host computer rebooted.

### Observations

1)
Although I, personally, had not changed anything, my computer crashed (it sent a report as well), but also came back with a forced Windows update. (Yay?)

2)
My VM was running at the time of the crash.

3)
After the computer rebooted, it did not reboot in the native resolution.  Visually, the desktop icons were not the same size or in their original places.  For example, my setting is normally 3840x2160, but had dropped to 1920x1080, and the native resolution was no longer an option.  (Do an internet search for checking monitor resolution if you need to).

### Conclusion

Even though I had "Use host setting for monitors" selected, I would submit it was not actually the VM's issue per se, it was my host computer.

### Additional Info (probably irrelevant)

It is a laptop that I run with the lid closed.  Under most circumstances, it transfers the monitor rights to my external monitor.  In effect, though, I have two monitors.

### My Solution

I rebooted my computer until it picked up the native resolution and my VM worked fine again.

### Best Guess

VMWare still had knowledge of the native resolution, but Windows was stuck displaying a lower resolution - maybe a "safe mode" flag that got set somehow, but nothing else was in "safe mode," so very weird.